# Python output excel file

Tags: python, excel

I run the following code to output the result of correlating these columns in the compiler

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('new_file.xlsx', sheet_name='pack')
df.groupby(['STYLE', 'BRAND NAME', 'PRODUCT DESCRIPTION', 'COLOR','Size','SIZE RANGE', 'Retail Price','WEBSITE COUNTRY', 'SKU','BARCODE']).sum
```

but i want to output the complete results in excel

I modified the following code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('new_file.xlsx', sheet_name='pack')
df = df.groupby(['STYLE', 'BRAND NAME', 'PRODUCT DESCRIPTION', 'COLOR','Size','SIZE RANGE', 'Retail Price','WEBSITE COUNTRY', 'SKU','BARCODE']).sum
df.to_excel('result.xlsx', index=False)
```

but output result is only column about 'sum'
i want to output the complete results in excel inclouding 'STYLE', 'BRAND NAME', 'PRODUCT DESCRIPTION', 'COLOR','Size','SIZE RANGE', 'Retail Price','WEBSITE COUNTRY', 'SKU','BARCODE' those columns

Comment: why don't you use `df = df['STYLE', 'BRAND NAME', 'PRODUCT DESCRIPTION', 'COLOR','Size','SIZE RANGE', 'Retail Price','WEBSITE COUNTRY', 'SKU','BARCODE']` and then output it to excel?

Comment: Once you are doing groupby and assigning it to the existing df (on the line df = df.groupby()) then you are effectively only storing the updated data frame, the earlier one is lost. Keep two copies of the data frame and append the grouped one to the original one post-processing.

Comment: In fact, there is also a quantity column, which needs to be obtained by associating these columns

Comment: I can complete the output in the compiler, but I want the output to be excel. How can I modify it?

Answer (score 0):

just delete 'index=False' it worked  although i don't know why